# XML columns compare in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I have got 3 columns:

1. [OldContent] [xml] NULL
2. [NewContent] [xml] NULL
3. [OldContent] [xml] NULL

I want to compare the data in two columns. I want to write the results into the third column (`[OldContent]`)

How can I do it in SQL Server?

[OldContent] [xml] NULL, in

Value

```
<row GUEST_ID="13" GUEST_NAME="VEDAT" GUEST_SURNAME="PALA" ADRESS="IZMIR" />
```

[NewContent] [xml] NULL, in value

```
<row GUEST_ID="13" GUEST_NAME="VEDAT35" GUEST_SURNAME="PALA" ADRESS="IZMIR" CITY="DR" CITY_CODE="35" />
```

I want to write the value in it.

```
[UpdateContent] [xml] NULL

<row GUEST_NAME="VEDAT35 CITY="DR" CITY_CODE="35" />
```

I need a procedure to compare XML column values.

[image]

[image]

Comment: take xml data and form a table using x query then compare the tables.,or convert it to nvarchar and just do string comparison

Answer (score 0):

It is quite easy to get the data out of XML. Then you may compare your data "as ever". The result you can write out into a new XML with "FOR XML".

Try it like this:

```
DECLARE @myXML XML=
'<rows>
 <row GUEST_ID="13" GUEST_NAME="VEDAT35" GUEST_SURNAME="PALA" ADRESS="IZMIR" CITY="DR" CITY_CODE="35" />
 <row GUEST_ID="14" GUEST_NAME="TestGuestName" GUEST_SURNAME="TestSurname" ADRESS="TestAddr" CITY="TestCity" CITY_CODE="11" />
 </rows>';

--This is how you retrieve the data 
SELECT x.y.value('@GUEST_ID','int')
      ,x.y.value('@GUEST_NAME','varchar(max)')
      ,x.y.value('@GUEST_SURNAME','varchar(max)')
      ,x.y.value('@ADRESS','varchar(max)')
      ,x.y.value('@CITY','varchar(max)')
      ,x.y.value('@CITY_CODE','int')
FROM @myXML.nodes('/rows/row') AS x(y)

--This is how you create a new XML with your data
SELECT 13 AS [@GUEST_ID]
      ,'NewName' AS [@GUEST_NAME]
      ,'NewSurname' AS [@GUEST_SURNAME]      
      ,'NewAddr' AS [@GUEST_ADRESS]      
      ,'NewCity' AS [@CITY]
      ,12 AS [@CITY_CODE]
FOR XML PATH('row'),ROOT('rows')
```

Comment: Fields count is variables.   I want to compare field value and fields count.

Comment: You will not find a solution which can deal with any variable XML... SQL Server can handle XML-Data pretty well, but you must assume some sort of structure... Please provide more sample data and expected output...

Comment: I have got more  Tables in DB.. I need procedure for xml..Because i have got more more fields..

Answer (score 0):

samples  table

```
USE [DENEME]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[GUESTS]    Script Date: 17.07.2015 22:19:35         ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[GUESTS](
[GUEST_ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[GUEST_NAME] [varchar](50) NULL,
[GUEST_SURNAME] [varchar](50) NULL,
[ADRESS] [varchar](100) NULL,
[CITY] [varchar](50) NULL,
[CITY_CODE] [varchar](10) NULL,
[COUNTRY] [varchar](50) NULL,
[STATUS] [varchar](20) NULL,
[COMMENT] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[GUEST_ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,         ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO


USE [DENEME]
GO
/****** Object:  Trigger [dbo].[iudt_AutoAuditChanges]    Script Date:     17.07.2015 22:20:11 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[iudt_AutoAuditChanges] 
ON  [dbo].[GUESTS]
AFTER INSERT,DELETE,UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
declare @AuditType char(1) /* BEN EKELEDM*/
Declare @v_AuditID bigint

/******************************/
if exists (select * from inserted) 
if exists (select * from deleted) 
SET @AuditType = 'U' 
else 
SET @AuditType = 'I' 
else 
SET @AuditType = 'D'
/******************************/

IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.AutoAudit','U') IS NULL BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AutoAudit]
    (   [AuditID] bigint identity,
        [AuditType] Char(1), 
        [AuditDate] DateTime,
        [AuditUserName] varchar(128),
        [TableName] varchar(128) NULL,
        [OldContent] XML NULL,
        [NewContent] XML NULL,
        [Updatedcontent] XML NULL
    )

    ALTER TABLE dbo.AutoAudit ADD CONSTRAINT
    PK_AutoAudit PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [AuditID]
    ) WITH( STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,     ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]

    CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [idx_AutoAudit_TableName_AuditDate] ON [dbo].    [AutoAudit] 
      (   [TableName] ASC,
        [AuditDate] ASC
    )WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF,     IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON,     ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
    END

Select * Into #AuditDeleted from deleted
Select * Into #AuditInserted from inserted

While (Select COUNT(*) from #AuditDeleted) > 0 OR (Select COUNT(*) from     #AuditInserted) > 0
Begin

    INSERT INTO [dbo].[AutoAudit]
        ( [AuditDate],[AuditType], [AuditUserName], [TableName],     [OldContent], [NewContent])
    SELECT 
        GETDATE(),
        @AuditType,
        SUSER_NAME(),
        [TableName]=object_name([parent_obj]),
        [OldContent]=CAST((SELECT TOP 1 * FROM #AuditDeleted D FOR XML RAW)     AS xml),
        [NewContent]=CAST((SELECT TOP 1 * FROM #AuditInserted I FOR XML RAW)     AS xml)
    FROM sysobjects 
    WHERE
        [xtype] = 'tr' 
        and [name] = OBJECT_NAME(@@PROCID)

    Set @v_AuditID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

    Delete from AutoAudit
    Where AuditID = @v_AuditID
        AND Convert(varchar(max),oldContent) =     Convert(varchar(max),NewContent)

    Delete top(1) from #AuditDeleted
    Delete top(1) from #AuditInserted

    End
END
```

I am writing  log program.
OldContent:

```
<row GUEST_ID="19" GUEST_NAME="VEDAT" GUEST_SURNAME="PALA" ADRESS="TURKEY" CITY="TOKAT" CITY_CODE="60" />
```

newcontent:

```
<row GUEST_ID="19" GUEST_NAME="VEDAT60" GUEST_SURNAME="PALA" ADRESS="TURKEY"     CITY="TOKAT" CITY_CODE="60" STATUS="other" COMMENT="uptaded  fields" />
```

Expected results:
UptadedContent:

```
<row GUEST_NAME="VEDAT60" STATUS="other" COMMENT="uptaded  fields" />
```

I want compare procedure..
Look this picture
IMG]http://i59.tinypic.com/24nfibl.png[/IMG]